# Is there a way to detect programmatically whether a Docker container is running natively or using Docker Machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jmx, docker-machine

Is there a way to find out from inside a Docker container whether that container is running natively on a Linux host, or in Docker Machine?

The background of the question is that I want to enable JMX in my Tomcat-based container, but for that, I need to know the external IP address of the host:

- When running in Docker-Machine, this is something like 192.168.99.100.
- Running natively on Linux, this is the IP address of the host.
- Running in Docker for Mac, this is also the IP address of the host.

I have a Docker Tomcat image that I want to roll out with JMX enabled, but I don't know whether people are going to use it natively or running in Docker-Machine, hence I don't know which IP address to provide for the `java.rmi.server.hostname` parameter when starting Tomcat.

Is there a way to either

- find that IP address from inside of the container (or find out where it's running), or
- find it out from the outside (e.g. in docker-compose) and then pass it into the container upon start? Can the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable help in this case? When running Docker Machine, it's set to `tcp://192.168.99.100:2376`- is this variable also used when not running Docker Machine?

I would like to avoid the situation where people have to provide the IP address manually when starting the container (or Docker Compose).

Comment: regarding to your second option, you can use [docker api](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) and get information regarding to your container!

Comment: @Mohsen89z what would you query in docker to find out what type of host you are running on?

Comment: I think that's going to be hard to do without injecting an environment variable at run time from the host running it. You could possibly set up a script for people to run your containers that collects the info for them. or maybe try [jolokia](https://jolokia.org) which suits being run in docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I have solved this by using the `DOCKER_HOST` variable. My assumption is that if this variable is set, it will contain the IP address of the host, in the form of `tcp://192.168.99.100:2367`.

In my `docker-compose.yaml` file, I have mapped the host's `DOCKER_HOST` variable into the container:

```
version: "2"

services:
  foo:
    environment:
      DOCKER_HOST: $DOCKER_HOST
```

Then in the container, I evaluate this variable as part of the script that is run when the container is started, and then use it to set Tomcat's JMX properties:

```
# Allow to specify the JMX port from the outside. Use 10992 as a default if not provided
DOCKER_JMX_PORT=${DOCKER_JMX_PORT:-10992}

# Evaluate the $DOCKER_HOST variable
if [ -n "DOCKER_HOST" ]; then
  # DOCKER_HOST variable is set
  DOCKER_JMX_HOST=$(echo "$DOCKER_HOST" | sed -e "s|tcp://||g" -e "s/:.*//g")
else
  # DOCKER_HOST variable is not set
  DOCKER_JMX_HOST=$(hostname)
fi

# Set the JMX properties for Tomcat
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$DOCKER_JMX_PORT \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$DOCKER_JMX_PORT \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$DOCKER_JMX_HOST"
```

When the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable is not set, I assume that the container is running natively, e.g. on Linux, and I use the hostname for the JMX properties.